# How to refresh state in Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, alpine-linux

Hi guys i am trying to hide my mobile menu when the window is resized above it breakpoint. I have implemented the Alpine.js and it seems to work fine but however when i try to access its x-data to set the boolean to false which should hide, it just doesn't do anything.

```
<body x-data="{ open: false, navbar: false, resDrop: false }">
  <div class="md:hidden" :class="{'block': navbar, 'hidden': !navbar}">
    <div><span></span></div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

And when i try to

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    let data = document.querySelector('[x-data]');
      
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        return data.__x.getUnobservedData().navbar = false;
    }
};
```

to return the navbar to its initial close state it just doesn't work. Any way i can achieve this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Switched to this, now its working perfectly.

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    let data = document.querySelector('[x-data]');
      
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        return data.__x.$data.navbar = false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `x-on:resize.window` along the lines of:

```js
<nav 
  x-data="{ navbar: false }" 
  x-on:resize.window="navbar = (window.outerWidth >= 768) ? true : false"
>
  <div class="md:hidden" :class="{'block': navbar, 'hidden': !navbar}">
    Nav Content
  </div>
</nav>
```

Also, from a performance stand, it is best to have your state on the component, not on the `<body>`, so alpine has less nodes to go traverse. This is also better to keep components scoped, avoiding them sharing unrelated state in the same object and to simply making your components portable.